# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'

Tags: java, android

Me salió este error de repente, me marca la clase R en rojo en el código Java.

AAPT err(Facade for 557143976): libpng error: Not a PNG file

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>   Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

Ya use Rebuild Project y Clean Project varias veces...

Comment: ¿Tienes importado  `R`?  `import com.tuPackage.app.R`. Intenta limpiar el proyecto y después `Rebuild`.

Comment: Te diriges a `Build>Clean Project` después a  `Build>Rebuild Project`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este detalle no se puede resolver con : 
`Build` > `Rebuild Project` .

Te sugiero actualizar la versión de gradle!, en mi caso uso:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
}
```

El problema también puede deberse a algun problema en los recursos, por ejemplo si cambiaste la extension de archivos de imagenes de .jpg a .png Android Studio detecta que en realidad no es un recurso con formato .png, por esa razón puede marcar error.

Lo que tienes que realizar en este caso es abrir el archivo .jpg con algun programa para manipular imagenes y salvarlo con formato .png

Comment: Nada, no lo logro resolver el error, intente traspasar todo mi codigo de un proyecto a otro cambiando lo que tenía que cambiar... No he podido seguir trabajando.

Comment: No te desesperes Victor, que mensaje ves en el Event Logo en el LogCat?

Comment: En el Event Log solo   
Gradle build finished with 1 error(s) in 43s 137ms  
y en Gradle Console  
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.  

* What went wrong:  
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.  
> Some file crunching failed, see logs for details  

* Try:  
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --   debug option to get more log output.

Comment: ok , tienes algún mensaje "Crunching Cruncher" dentro de tu consola, similar a esto? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30764604/execution-failed-for-task-appmergedebugresources-crunching-cruncher-png-fa

Comment: Si era un problema con algún archivo de recursos verdad? Aún así ese problema debe no presentarse si actualizas según algunos usuarios.

Comment: Si, borre me ultimo comentario para verificar. Al parecer si lo era... Pero no entiendo, lo cambiaba y daba el mismo error, entonces pase los archivos uno por uno. Al parecer quedo un directorio viejo que no podía ver ni desde la vista Project.

Comment: Buen dia, veo que indican que para resolver este error actualice el gradle de esta manera: dependencies { classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
} Pero cuando pongo esto me manda error que el metodo classpath no existe, saben porque es esto?? Utilizo Android estudio 2.2