# ¿Cómo solucionar este problema al construir un APK en Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

Tengo el siguiente error al crear un *APK*:

> Error: Execution failed for task `:app:mergeDebugResources`.
>
> Error: `java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException`:
> `com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException`:

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el **[recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)** y lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. Por favor revisa [qué funciones tiene el sitio para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tu pregunta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78).

Comment: Revisa esta [respuesta _(en inglés)_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19242929/4092887). Busca también: `java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException`. **[edit] tu pregunta** agregando el código que usas y que te genera este error.

Comment: Posible duplicado : http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/10988/errorexecution-failed-for-task-appmergedebugresources